# How to chage CSS attributes of a Div when another Div is hovered that is located after the first Div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, mousehover

I have DIV 1 and DIV 2. In the code Div 2 is located after Div 1. I want to change the background colour of Div 1 when Div 2 is hovered. 
Preferebly I do not want to change the HTML structure and do not want to use JS.

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}
  
span:hover div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div>I will show on hover</div>
<span>Hover over me!</span>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want if you change the order in which the `div` and `span` are generated. If you don't want to change the order of elements it isn't possible without JS.

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}
  
span:hover + div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span>Hover over me!</span>
<div>I will show on hover</div>
```